MS Word solutions to compare two files and automatically extract changes
On of the greatest pain points of my work is to compare two MS Word documents and extract differences between previous and the new one in the tabular format.
I was wondering, is there a smart solution to compare documents and get differences extracted? VBA code or some other smart solution?
Thank you in advance!
I tried VBA, but failed to write it by myself as I an a new in VBA
Commercial software is banned in my company, so I need to find solution that would be using internal tools like VBA or MS toolkit itself

Activate Review > Track Changes on the Word Ribbon before making any changes. It's the easiest and most reliable way to track modifications. MS Documentation Track changes in Word

I think, I have not clarified the issue clearly: I have no issue doing it manually, but it takes so much time and effort that could go to other tasks.
My question is more about how to automate it, that it would take sentence by sentence and put old vs new in the tabular format. I

You could combine all the changes into a new document then use the method on this link to export the changes to an excel workbook - https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40314-exporting-tracked-changes-comments-excel.html
